# K-Means Clustering Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

### When I run the below code I keep getting an error

```
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
df <- USArrests
df <- na.omit(df)
df<- scale(df)
distance <- get_dist(df)
k2<- kmeans(df,centers = 2,nstart = 25)
k2$cluster
fviz_cluster(k2, data = df)
```

---

**Code Error**

> df<- scale(df)
>   Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
>     cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'
>   distance <- get_dist(df)
>   Error in as.vector(x, mode) : 
>     cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue, code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The error I was facing was due to `df <- USArrests` the data in USArrests was not correctly imported, so I used `data(USArrests)` then the code worked.